# Matlab plot label individually

Tags: matlab

I would like to make individual label for each and every tick in matlab plot. I could do this by

```
xtick = [1, 10, 20]; 
xticklabels = {'January', 'February', 'December'};
set(gca, 'XTick', xtick);
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', xticklabels);
```

As the strings are very long, I would like to make them in a slanting way. So I would be very happy, if anyone could help me in displaying the label in a slanting way.

Thanks

Comment: Try the file exchange, it has many options for example this http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27812-rotate-x-axis-tick-labels or this http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8722-rotate-tick-label or this http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486-xticklabel-rotate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had a somewhat similar problem and I found an example on Matlab answers by The Mathworks. Basically you create text objects with your labels and rotate them. Otherwise there is a submission on the File Exchange [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27812-rotate-x-axis-tick-labels) that looks pretty nice. Hope that helps!

```
clear
clc

% Generate some test data.  Assume that the X-axis represents months.
x = 1:12;
y = 10*rand(1,length(x));

% Plot the data.
h = plot(x,y,'+');

% Reduce the size of the axis so that all the labels fit in the figure.
pos = get(gca,'Position');
set(gca,'Position',[pos(1), .2, pos(3) .65])

% Add a title.
title('This is a title')

% Set the X-Tick locations so that every other month is labeled.
Xt = 1:2:11;
Xl = [1 12];
set(gca,'XTick',Xt,'XLim',Xl);

% Add the months as tick labels.
months = ['Jan';
          'Feb';
          'Mar';
          'Apr';
          'May';
          'Jun';
          'Jul';
          'Aug';
          'Sep';
          'Oct';
          'Nov';
          'Dec'];
ax = axis;    % Current axis limits
axis(axis);    % Set the axis limit modes (e.g. XLimMode) to manual
Yl = ax(3:4);  % Y-axis limits

% Place the text labels
t = text(Xt,Yl(1)*ones(1,length(Xt)),months(1:2:12,:));
set(t,'HorizontalAlignment','right','VerticalAlignment','top', ...
      'Rotation',45);

% Remove the default labels
set(gca,'XTickLabel','')

% Get the Extent of each text object.  This

% loop is unavoidable.
for i = 1:length(t)
  ext(i,:) = get(t(i),'Extent');
end
% Determine the lowest point.  The X-label will be
% placed so that the top is aligned with this point.
LowYPoint = min(ext(:,2));
% Place the axis label at this point
XMidPoint = Xl(1)+abs(diff(Xl))/2;
tl = text(XMidPoint,LowYPoint,'X-Axis Label', ...
          'VerticalAlignment','top', ...
          'HorizontalAlignment','center');
```